# GParted can't make physical xfs partition smaller, but can make larger

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, gparted, xfs

I have read all topics about partition resizing, GParted FAQ. In my case I can't resize my (sda1) physical xfs partition (make it smaller), but can make it larger.
[image]

I tried it from my real linux system, from boot-usb with gparted and I have same results.
Which tool can help me? Or what I need to do to make my sda1 partition smaller?
Thanks in advance.

PS: /home directories are encrypted, possible it can affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the underlying xfs tools (or even of xfs itself), not of gparted.

There is a command `xfs_growfs` (see `man xfs_growfs`), but no generic *xfs_resize* or *xfs_shrinkfs*. You can only expand an XFS, not shrink it.

See also

- https://xfs.org/index.php/Shrinking_Support
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_growfs

So you'll have to take an extra step to make a backup to external media (e.g. an USB disk), delete the existing partitions and create new ones, and then restore your backup.

While you are at it, you might reconsider your partition layout: With only two partitions it makes little sense to use an *extended* partition for the second one. This would also be an obstacle for resizing because you can't simply move the extended partition (/dev/sda2) backwards. Also, consider using the GPT partitioning scheme where you don't have to mess with extended partitions at all.

Since you will want to boot from that new /dev/sda1, you might also have to create a small *BIOS boot* partition where Grub2 (the bootloader) can embed itself; unlike ext4, xfs does not support that directly.